# Accessibility, fieldset legends, and header tags

Tags: accessibility, forms

A requirement of a site I am developing is that it must be 508 compliant.  Currently most of our html views start with a header `h1` and then whatever needs to be on that view.  Now for forms, it is recommended to use `fieldset`s and `legend`s when dealing with accessibility, among other numerous guidelines.  This makes things a little more complicated because the `h1` was to be the title of the content, but if I have to use a `fieldset` and a legend, now I have an `h1` title but the legend title would pretty much be the same thing.  For example:

```
<h1>Edit Education Details</h1>

  <form>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Edit Education Details</legend>

      <p>
        <label for="school">School</label>
        <input id="school" name="school" type="text"/>
      </p>

      ...other fields

    </fieldset>      
  </form>
```

I'm not sure which route to go. Should I just get rid of the `h1` and style the legend to be the same as the `h1` styling?  Or should I get creative with the legend text so that they aren't the exact same text?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Leave the `h1` as is (assuming that Education Details is the only thing you can edit on that screen) and use `fieldset/legend` to group any related form controls. For instance, lets say you have a series of checkboxes that deal with the user's level of education completed:

```
<h1>Edit Education Details</h1>

<form>

<p>
  <label for="school">School</label>
  <input id="school" name="school" type="text"/>
</p>
<fieldset>
  <legend>Level of Education Completed</legend>
  <input type="checkbox" id="highschool">
  <label for="highschool">High School</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="associates">
  <label for="associates">Associates Degree</label>
  [...]
</fieldset>      
</form>
```

If there are not any logically associated sections of inputs in the form, then omit the `fieldset/legends`. Having redundancy or "getting creative" so that you aren't redundant isn't going to enhance the accessibility.

See [WCAG 2.0 - H82: Grouping form controls with FIELDSET and LEGEND](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-WCAG20-TECHS-20080430/H82.html).

Comment: Yea I went with the h1 and your comments make perfect sense.  Thanks for that link as well.