# Semantic Markup for multiple choice questions

Tags: html, forms

**What did you have for dinner?**

- Beef
- Chicken
- Fish
- Vegetables

Let's assume this above is one question in a long questionnaire and the bullets are mutually exclusive radio buttons.

What is the best way to markup this HTML semantically?

Do I use `<label>What did you have for dinner?</label>`

or do I use some other html construct?

Answer (score 2):

A good way to do this is to place the `label`s wrapping each radio option, and then if you want full accessibility support, use an [`aria-labelledby` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-labelledby_attribute) for the group:

```
<span id="label-dinner">What did you have for dinner?</span>
<div class="controls" aria-labelledby="label-dinner">
    <label><input type="radio" name="dinner" />Beef</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="dinner" />Chicken</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="dinner" />Fish</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="dinner" />Vegetables</label>
</div>
```

Comment: The correct markup for the example above would be a `legend` instead of a `span`, all enclosed in `fieldset`. Then the `aria-labelledby` (while not incorrect) wouldn't be necessary. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/15560982/504745